# TypeError when extending abstract class with static factory method

Tags: typescript, inheritance, static-methods

I have an abstract class A, with a static method that instantiates one of two classes extending it depending on an object parameter, calling their own `fromValue` static method.

```
abstract class A {
  
  static fromValue(p: any): A {
    if (p.type === 'whatever1') 
      return B.fromValue(p);
    if (p.type === 'whatever2') 
      return C.fromValue(p);
    throw new Error('invalid parameter');
  }

  abstract doSomething(): string

}

class B extends A {
  static fromValue(p: any): B {
    //do something with p and finally return a B
  }
}

class C extends A {
  static fromValue(p: any): C {
    //do something with p and finally return a C
  }
}
```

When I run this test with Jest:

```
describe("A.fromValue", () => {
  test("creates instances", () => {
    const a = A.fromValue({ type: "whatever1" });
    
    //assert stuff
  });
});
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

If I move `A::fromValue` method to another class, say `AFactory`, I get no errors.

After googling it, I found it may be related to circular dependencies but I can't see any here. I'm starting with Typescript and I would like to understand what's happening.

Comment: no error here https://tsplay.dev/wEPVgW

Comment: Works just fine for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.7.2#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

Comment: I have pasted my exact code (not the example) in the playground and it's working fine, too. I'm using the same TS version. I don't understand what's happening. Maybe it's because of Jest test runner: I'm getting the error when I run tests